# Why is the usb shield always tied to ground (GND pin)?

Tags: usb, connector, grounding, shielding, ground-loop

The shielding on a cable is to avoid interference from the outside world however it is always tied directly to the GND pin. Not inside the cable itself but inside a device. Every single device I take a look at, will do this, computer/hubs, usb soundcards, usb bluetooth dongles, usb powerbanks, usb harddrives, arduino's etc.

In my perspective this make no sense at all because the shielding is now acting like a big attenna instead of a faraday cage, or am I wrong? I think this a source of noise and/or ground loop problems.

What is de reason why they doing this?

---

Example, when measuring resistance between shield and GND pin, it reads 0 ohm:
[image: usb connector example]

Comment: Sometimes its tied via Ferrite Beads and it will also read 0 Ohm. Also, maybe its not a good idea to refer to GND as "minus pin" in the USB context because USB also has Data plus and Data minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been discussed over many entries on SE EE and elsewhere.

See

[USB Shield. To ground or not to ground?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/389972/117785)
[How to connect USB Connector shield?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/4515/117785)
[USB 3.0 Hub shield connection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/291380/117785)

[Does an overvoltage TVS for USB hot-plugging connect to shield ground?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/307883/117785)

and most elaborate answer is provided here, [Structure of a usb 2.0 connector [duplicate]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/269313/117785)

It explains that the shiled serves two contradictory functions, (1) provides the path for ESD discharge, and (2) shields EMI from noise of internal digital ground. So the trade-offs must be made, depending on particular shape of USB device - handheld, grounded enclosure, etc.