# Can the USB port's metal enclosure be grounded?

Tags: pcb, usb, short-circuit, ground-plane

As shown in the image below, the USB port's metal enclosure is touching the copper clad of the PCB (which is a ground plane).

Can Bad Things Happen™ if the port's enclosure is grounded?

I beep-tested the 4 pins with the enclosure, and none of them are connected to it. However, could some shorts be made when plugging something into the port?

[image: 1]

Comment: It *should* be grounded. However, which ground it should be connected to (chassis/safety/signal/power) could be a different matter.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere -- Thanks for the comment! We only have one ground in our design (both our signals and power share the ground plane). Would it have to be a different ground?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere -- I presume we'd need a chassis ground. Since its the only thing in our project that could be considered a "chassis", would we still need one?

Comment: It depends on what kind of product we're dealing with.

Comment: Regarding shielding/grounding, see here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/408044/117785

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are not more than one GND then yes it is recommended to Ground the USB port enclosure.

For more information please look at this thread. [USB Shield. To ground or not to ground?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389972/usb-shield-to-ground-or-not-to-ground)